# integrate pm2 with socket io in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, adapter, pm2

can't use adapter with socket io in production although it's running in development
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiyLf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3LCj.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncrog.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care about version campatibility between your server and client .

https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).